# ST_SetSRID ST_Point PostGIS giving strange output

Tags: postgis, point, geography

The statement...

`ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(11.243534634635, 32.54354365346), 4326)::geography`

gives me slightly different(off by 5%) output than the latitude (32.54354365346) and longitude(11.243534634635) I would expect. What can I do differently here? Is it a rounding or precision issue? Perhaps ST_Point is not the correct function?

Comment: Specifically, what value do you get? In what client? Your statement is otherwise good.

Comment: The numbers you put as expected are identical to those in your ST_Point statement. Where is the issues, exactly.

Comment: I think it was an issue with my SQL join statement. I did get it work now. But I get this NOTICE.... _NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY_  is that normal?

Comment: @Rabbitshoe that's not normal, and you will need to check those numbers.